# How to describe a locus

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exercise review: perpendicular-to-plane line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164110/exercise-review-perpendicular-to-plane-line)

I have a plane in affine space in  $\Bbb R^4$ described by two following equations:

\begin{Bmatrix}x+y-2z+q +2=0\\ -x-2y+3z+q=0\end{Bmatrix}

I have the coords of a point $P$: (1,2,3,4).

I have to describe the locus of all points $Q$ such that line $PQ$ is $\bot$ to the plane.

Comment: I think this combined system of equations represents a plane in $\Bbb R^3$(as one degree of freedom is lost by one extra equation) or you can say Line in $\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: Ok, but I think I have to say which equation(s) describe the line... can you help?

Comment: @avatar I think the OP is saying that the two equations cut the dimension down by two, and that a plane (as opposed to a hyperplane?) in $\mathbb R^4$ means "something $2$-dimensional".

Comment: Repaired; and cleared off-topic comments. Also retagged both this and duplicate target.

Comment: Dear @Willie, thanks for removing the off-topic comments.